# VBA - Sort a single column based upon values in another, non-adjacent column

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Suppose I have the following range in an Excel (2016) worksheet:

```
Sort Order:    Col1:    Col2:
3              A        A
4              B        B
2              C        C
1              D        D
```

And **I want to leave all the other columns unchanged**, but sort `Col2` based upon the values in the `Sort Order` column. So the final result would be:

```
Sort Order:    Col1:    Col2:
3              A        D
4              B        C
2              C        A
1              D        B
```

In words, I want to sort a specific column based upon another, non-adjacent column's values without affecting any other column in my range.

I know I could go the route of making a copy of the range and pasting back the original values in everything but the column I want sorted, but I'm not a HUGE fan of that one if I can get away without having to do that. Otherwise, I'd imagine I could import the range in as an array and implement my own sort procedure from that point (if you have simple code to do this, though, please do share), but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Put the columns that you want to remain unchanged in to an array -- this should be arguably faster / more efficient than making a copy of the Range or Sheet object. Then use the built in method(s) to `Sort` the range. Of course this will affect all of the columns, but you've got the array from earlier, so just dump the array back to the sheet for the unchanged columns.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidZemens, I was thinking even the opposite, to make a new range with just the sorting column and the column I want sorted, do the sort and then paste back column 2. Just hoping there's a better way still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @DavidZemens, @Xabier and @GarysStudent supplied really good answers - Both using VBA and Excel functions, I ended up making up my own that:

1. Copied only the (1) Column to sort by (`Sort Order`) & (2) Column to be sorted (`Col2`) into a new, blank range.
2. Sorted that range based upon the first column
3. Copied the second column back over the original column I wanted sorted

The reason I went with that implementation is because:

1. It allowed for any kind of values in the `Sort Order` column
2. It allowed me to extend it to multiple columns / allow for looping (which I needed) by paramaterizing it.

Here's my solution:

```
Sub Tester()

' The data we want sorted and the column to sort by:
Dim SortByCol As Range
Dim ToSortCol As Range
    Set SortByCol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A7")
    Set ToSortCol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C7")


' An empty range to use for copying / pasting to:
Dim SortRange As Range
    Set SortRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    DoSort SortByCol, ToSortCol, SortRange
End Sub


Sub DoSort(SortByCol As Range, ToSortCol As Range, SortRange As Range)

    ' Copy our data to sort into a contiguous range so we can sort using Excel's native sort functionality:
    Union(SortByCol, ToSortCol).Copy SortRange

    ' Reset the SortRange to the entire pasted in region:
    Set SortRange = SortRange.CurrentRegion

    ' Sort the SortRange:
    With SortRange.Parent.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=SortRange.Range("A1:A" & SortRange.Rows.Count), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .SetRange SortRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' Copy the second column back into the ToSort Column:
    SortRange.Columns(2).Copy ToSortCol

    SortRange.Clear
End Sub
```

However, I will say the other solutions presented were perfect, but my specific situation was best handled using the code above.

Thanks again to @DavidZemes, @Xabier and @GarysStudent!!

Answer (score 3):

As per David Zemens comments, you can do this as follows:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
'declare and set the Worksheet you are working with, amend as require
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

Arr = ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow) 'add values from column B into an Array

    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:C" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    'sort on column A
ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value = Arr 'add the values of the array back into Column B
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very possibly the easiest way... Just wish Excel had a native way to sort non-contiguous columns.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, just for fun, using the [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to leverage its built-in `Sort` method.

Should be self-explanatory, but if not, here goes...

We cache the original values of `colToSort` in `originalValues` array, and define our ArrayList using the "Sort Order" column, then apply the `Sort` method to the `sortList` object.

Still haven't sorted anything on the worksheet, but now we can iterate the `sortList` and `Index` against the `originalValues` to write out to the sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortThis()
Dim sortList As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim sortOrder As Range
Dim colToSort As Range
Dim originalValues

Set sortList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set sortOrder = Range("A2:A5")
Set colToSort = Range("C2:C5")

originalValues = colToSort.Value
ReDim sortedValues(UBound(originalValues))

For i = 1 To sortOrder.Cells.Count
    sortList.Add (sortOrder.Cells(i).Value2)
Next

sortList.Sort

With Application
    For i = 0 To sortList.Count - 1
        sortedValues(i) = .Index(originalValues, .Match(sortList(i), sortOrder, False), 1)
    Next
    colToSort.Value = .Transpose(sortedValues)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Really interesting!!

Comment: @JohnBustos made a small revision to reduce the number of `.Value` assignments on the worksheet :)

Comment: I do like this, but feel like the line `sortedValues(i) = .Index(originalValues, .Match(sortList(i), sortOrder, False), 1)` could end up being pretty costly... VERY cool implementation / idea, though. I ended up going with a different solution, but thank you so much for even thinking of something quite so out-the-box!!

Answer (score 1):

With the sort order in column **A** and the data in column **C**, in **E2** enter:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),A:A,0))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If the values in column **A** are not simple sequential integers, then we can use a "helper column".  In **F2** enter:

```
=MIN(A:A)
```

and in **F3** enter the **array formula**:

```
=MIN(IF(A:A>F2,A:A,""))
```

and copy downwards.  **Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Then in **E2** enter:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(F2,A:A,0))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Note that the "helper" is really just a sorted version of column **A**.

Comment: Sorry, @GarysStudent, but will this only work for integers in the Sort Order column. That was just a very over-simplified example. It could be decimal values too...

Comment: @JohnBustos  See my **EDIT#1**